# Get an Array of days from first day of the month till today Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, calendar, iteration, swift3

I am new in iOS and programming and I need somehow to get an array from the first day of current month till today. And one array for past 3 months till today, but I have no idea how to do that, please any help or ideas?

I checked about this to get the first day of month:

```
extension Date {
func startOfMonth() -> Date? {
    let comp: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .hour], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self))
    return Calendar.current.date(from: comp)!
}
```

but it works only in a ViewController, what to do if do that in other part of my project? and also I have no idea how to iterate the array to get all the days between first day and today...

**EDIT**

I made something like this, but it gives ma an infinite loops.. what am I doing wrong?

```
    func weatherDatesFromCurrentDayMonth() -> [Any] {
    var date = Date()
    let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.month = -1
    //  dateComponents.day = 1
    let endingDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date)
    print("\(endingDate!)")
      var datesArray = Array<Any>()

    while date.compare(endingDate!) != ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = 1
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date)!
        datesArray.append(date)
        print("\(datesArray)")
    }

    return [datesArray]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having an endless loop because at the beginning your `endingDate` is already one month ago and `date` is now. Since inside the loop you only increment `date` it will never always be after `endingDate` and thus your condition is always `true`

Try this code:

```
func weatherDatesFromCurrentDayMonth() -> [Date] {
    let now = Date()
    var currentDate = previousMonth(date: now)
    var datesArray = [Date]()

    while currentDate < now {
        datesArray.append(currentDate)
        currentDate = nextDay(date:currentDate)
    }
    print("result: \(datesArray)")
    return datesArray
}

func nextDay(date: Date) -> Date {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = 1
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date)!
}

func previousMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.month = -1
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date)!
}
```